# How to detect opposite side of the bracket

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object

The issue im having with my code is that i want it to detect the opposite side of the bracket. I have separated the sides of the brackets into separate objects called rightCount and leftCount. These objects show the number of each of the bracket sides.
If the left side is more than the right, this means that one bracket pair is incomplete and is therefore an invalid bracket. Can someone help me fix my code so it has the ability to detect the brackets? Thank you.

```
const isValid = (parenthesis) => {
    if(typeof(parenthesis) !== "string" ){
        return false
    }
    const countLeft = {}
    const countRight = {}
    
     //check and see if the number of the 
     //left side is equal to the number of the closing brackets (right side)
        for(let i = 0; i < parenthesis.length; i++){
            if(!countLeft[parenthesis[i]] && parenthesis[i] === "{" || parenthesis[i] === '[' || parenthesis[i] === '(' ){
            countLeft[parenthesis[i]] = 1
            }
            else {
                countLeft[parenthesis[i]]++
            }
        };
        for(let i = 0; i < parenthesis.length; i++){
            if(!countRight[parenthesis[i]] && parenthesis[i] === "}" || parenthesis[i] === ']' || parenthesis[i] === ')' ){
                countRight[parenthesis[i]] = 1
                }
                else {
                    countRight[parenthesis[i]]++
                }
        }

        //The only issue with this is that it cant detect opposite sides of the bracket. It will only search for the same side in the other object
        for(let bracket in countLeft){
            if(countRight[bracket]){
                return true
            }
            else{
                return false
            }
        }

        for(let bracket in countRight){
            if(countleft[bracket]){
                return true
            }
            else{
                return false
            }
        }

        console.log(countLeft) 
        console.log(countRight) 

    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Use a [stack](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/solving-balanced-brackets-in-javascript-with-stacks-edbc52a57309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is also called as Balanced parentheses.
Basically the idea is to create a Stack like data structure. Then when you encounter a Opening Bracket, push it into the stack. Whenever you encounter a closing bracket pop from the Stack, and check if it's the corresponding bracket that you want to remove. If not return false as they aren't balanced . Finally if there are no elements in your stack the function can return true to denote that it is balanced.

[Check this link for more info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/)

EDIT:
I have implemented the same in your code:

```
const isValid = (parenthesis) => {
    if(typeof(parenthesis) !== "string" ){
        return false
    }
    const stack = []
    const mapClosingBrackets = {
        "{":"}",
        "[":"]",
        "(":")"
    }
    const characters = parenthesis.split("")
    for(let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
        if(characters[i] === "{" || characters[i] === '[' || characters[i] === '(' ){
            stack.push(characters[i])
        }
        else if(characters[i] === "}" || characters[i] === ']' || characters[i] === ')' ){
            let poppedValue = stack.pop()
            if(mapClosingBrackets[poppedValue]!=characters[i]){
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    if(stack.length) return false
    return true
    }
```

Comment: Hi Maria! Thanks for the link! I read through it, but is there a way to make my code balance the parenthesis?

Comment: Yeah it is possible. Instead a keeping a count of brackets, use an array to push the opening brackets inside. While you see a closing bracket pop it from the array and check if that's the desired one you want to remove. If yes no problem. If no return false at once

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm does not check whether the *order* of the opening brackets is inverse to the corresponding closing brackets.

Instead of keeping counters, determine the opposite bracket and push that character unto an array, so that you can verify that the upcoming closing bracket is really *that* type of bracket.

In this snippet you can input your string and it will tell you whether the parentheses match:

```js
function isValid(input) {
    let left = [];
    for (let chr of input) {
        if ("({[".includes(chr)) {
            // Determine the corresponding closing bracket
            left.push(")}]"["({[".indexOf(chr)]);
        } else if (")}]".includes(chr)) {
            let toMatch = left.pop(); // What was expected?
            if (chr !== toMatch) return false;
        }
    }
    return left.length === 0; // Only success if no pending closures
}

let input = document.querySelector("input");
let output = document.querySelector("div");

input.addEventListener("input", function () {
    output.textContent = isValid(this.value) ? "OK" : "Not matching";
});
```

```html
Type brackets:
<input>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Maria Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9993512/maria-charles)

> Instead a keeping a count of brackets, use an array to push the
> opening brackets inside. While you see a closing bracket pop it from
> the array and check if that's the desired one you want to remove. If
> yes no problem. If no return false at once.

Here is proper algorithm:

1. Declare a character stack which will hold an array of all the opening parenthesis.
2. Now traverse the expression string exp.
3. If the current character is a starting bracket (‘(‘ or ‘{‘ or ‘[‘) then push it to stack.
4. If the current character is a closing bracket (‘)’ or ‘}’ or ‘]’) then pop from stack and if the popped character is the matching starting bracket then fine else parenthesis are not balanced.
5. After complete traversal, if there is some starting bracket left in stack then “not balanced”

**Implementation in JavaScript:**

```js
    let isMatchingBrackets = function (str) {
    let stack = [];
    let map = {
        '(': ')',
        '[': ']',
        '{': '}'
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        // If character is an opening brace add it to a stack
        if (str[i] === '(' || str[i] === '{' || str[i] === '[' ) {
            stack.push(str[i]);
        }
        //  If that character is a closing brace, pop from the stack, which will also reduce the length of the stack each time a closing bracket is encountered.
        else {
            let last = stack.pop();

            //If the popped element from the stack, which is the last opening brace doesn’t match the corresponding closing brace in the map, then return false
            if (str[i] !== map[last]) {return false};
        }
    }
    // By the completion of the for loop after checking all the brackets of the str, at the end, if the stack is not empty then fail
        if (stack.length !== 0) {return false};

    return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yup made an edit similar to yours some minutes before your post. Thank you

Comment: Hi cstayyab! Thanks for this, what tips do you have on getting better with algorithms? Is there any Udemy course that you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter version to check valid bracket pairs.

```
const bracketValidator = str => {
  const sets = {'{': '}', '(': ')', '[': ']'};
  const stack = [];
  for (let brace of str) {
    if (sets[brace]) {
      stack.push(char);
    } else if (')]}'.includes(brace) && sets[stack.pop()] !== brace) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return !stack.length;
}
```

Comment: It might be nice to use `Object.values` on `sets` to find the characters we care about, and then change to `else if (closingBrackets.has(char) && sets[stack.pop()] !== char) ...`.  That lets us recognize strings like `'({foo, bar (baz) [[quz]]} corge)'` but catch that `'({foo, bar (baz) {[[quz]]} corge)'` has mismatched braces.